# javascript - strange debugging issue

Tags: javascript

My code changes are not being reflected in IE or FF.

In IE:
I commented out the alert('start'), but I still see the alert when I stop-restart my visual studio debugger.
In FF:
Same code change, but none of the alerts show at all.  I uncommented alert('start') and I still dont see it in FF.

I tried setting my port to stay fixed at 5204.  I also stopped the ASP.NET development server prior to starting the debugger again.  Still doesnt help.

Environment: VS 2010 IE7 and FF3.6.

Code

```
simplexhr = {
    doxhr: function (container, url) {
        //alert("START");
        if (!document.getElementById || !document.createTextNode) {
            alert("NO JS SUPPORT");
            return;
        }
        simplexhr.outputContainer = document.getElementById(container);
        if (!simplexhr.outputContainer) {
            alert("NO OUTPUT CONTAINER");
            return;
        }
        var request;
        try {
            //alert("Mozilla AJAX");
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            alert(request);
        }
        catch (error) {
            try {
                //alert("IE AJAX");
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (error) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 1)
                simplexhr.outputContainer.innerHTML = 'loading...';
        }
        alert("made it to try AJAX");
        request.open('get', url);
        //alert("ready state: " + request.readyState);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
On further testing, this problem is due to caching.  But, it only happens when I use "unobtrusive javascript" or javascript inside its own *.js file linked in the header:

```
<script src="Scripts/simpleXHR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Moving the code into the page - viewing source - the javascript updates everytime with no caching issues.  So is there a better way to perform "unobtrusive javascript"?  Or should it be renamed "unproductive javascript" :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it might be a browser cache issue.  Try clearing your cache in each browser.  Hopefully that will pick up the changes.

You could verify that by doing a view-source in the browser and see if you're actually getting the latest code.

Comment: Sure enough. Clearing the cache in both browsers made it stop. Thats kinda annoying. Does that mean I have to clear my browser cache everytime I make a code change in javascript?

Comment: If you are running your JS on local server (Apache or something), I think you can conf it so that it forces your browser to refresh cache.  In case that won't work for you, try testing the app in "private mode" of your browser (not cached).